# Rspec Controller testing with Javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2, rspec-rails

How do you test a controller in Rspec if the controller only responds with javascript? For example this would be my actual code:

some view.html.erb

```
link_to 'More Chips', add_chips_path, :remote => true
```

chips_controller

```
def add_chips
  Chips.create(:color => :red)
  @chips = Chips.all
end
```

add_chips.js.erb

```
$('#chip_count').html('<%=j render("chips/list", :chips => @chips) %>');
```

Rspec Test

spec/controllers/chips_controller_spec

```
it "should add chips" do 
  post :add_chips, :format => 'js'
end
```

When I try to post to this using RSpec I get a Missing Template error because it is sending an HTML request but there isn't an HTML view. I've tried passing in a format but that doesn't seem to work.  I know I can put in a "dummy" html view to make it pass but that seems like a hack.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what I was doing wrong.  I was passing a parameters hash in with my test and the format needs to be included in the same hash. so instead of this:

```
@params = {:chip_color => 'red'}
...
post :add_chips, @params, :format => 'js'
```

It needs to look like this

```
@params = {:chip_color => 'red', :format => 'js'}
...
post :add_chips, @params
```

Answer (score 47):

If you're trying to perform an Ajax request from a controller spec, instead of doing `post :add_chips` and passing the `format` as a parameter, you should do:

```
xhr :post, :add_chips, @params
```

...without `format` in params.  That will do a JavaScript request and respond with the `.js` template.

**Update:**

In recent versions of Rails/RSpec, you should instead do:

```
post :add_chips, params: @params, xhr: true
```